# Laravel Cashier - WebhookReceived vs WebhookHandled

Tags: laravel, laravel-cashier

On [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#defining-webhook-event-handlers) documentation, it said that both can be used, but what's the difference between the two? Their code seems to be identical as well.

Comment: Reception triggers before handling. both get the same payload

Comment: because it is common sense, never used it and just read the same docs yet figured it out. if i had a project running like you, i would have tried it and got my answer directly. The downvote is because this question will not be usefull in the future since you did not include any research done on your part (poor quality).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, it seems that `WebhookReceived` is triggered BEFORE Laravel Cashier do any logic with the webhook event, while `WebhookHandled` is triggered AFTER Laravel Cashier did their logic.

So if you received a `customer.subscription.created` event.

WebhookReceived will trigger before there are any data on the database with that event while WebhookHandled will trigger with the new subscription available in the database.